# What's the most complete calendar app for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation, calendar

I (and I think many of you) would like to find an iPhone calendar app that lets the user add an new event by touching the hour (no the day-view mode) and delay an event, instead of needing to enter, edit, change the time and finally save.

Is there such an app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm a big fan of [Calvetica](http://calvetica.com/), which can do the things you're looking for. And it's much prettier than the default iOS Calendar app.

Comment: Also a Calvetica fan. Took a little bit to get used to the interface, mostly due to how different it is from the built-in Calendar app, but now that I am I can't imagine going back.

Comment: Another Calvetica fan. The quick-add for new appointments is awesome.

Comment: I second Calivetica -


I just wish it would show the current day without it needing to be a badge

Comment: Almost perfect, but it doesn't show the "List View", that it's my preferred..

Comment: When you go edit the events details (after created) it have a ugly big page with no content on the bottom.. like a bug, but just an empty page that can bother if you scroll down..

Comment: @Tom Brito You mean list view as in just show a list of appointments? Thats how I keep it 24/7. Just click the icon furthest to the left in the day view.

Comment: @Gordon Fontenot: sorry, could you put an image? The only button I'm seeing in the left on day view is "Back". I would like to have a list containing only the events, not the empty hour, as you can see in the default system calendar, for reading. But, for adding events, the Day view is perfect.

Comment: @Tom Brito: Sorry, the bottom left. Unless I'm misunderstanding, this is what you're looking for? - http://cl.ly/4ge4

Comment: @Gordon Fontenot: I'm using the free version, if this makes any difference on that. In the bottom right there's an "Avisos" ("advices" in portuguese), and it lists the events almost as I wanted. I would like a list with the day and hour of the events, like the default calendar's list. This one is showing the hours remaining for the event. Can I configure this?

Comment: @Tom Brito: I'm not sure what you're looking for. Sorry.

Comment: The current (paid) version of Calvetica is very good now! Also, the WeekCal is a wonderful one!

Comment: The link you provided seems to go to some random Chinese website

Answer (score 2):

[Pocket Informant](http://webis.net/wp/pocket-informant/) is probably the most full featured I've seen - almost too full-featured, as it can be a bit overwhelming initially.  I use it's built in Google Sync functionality to sync directly to my Google Calendars from within the app itself.

Bonus points for the fact that it actually turns the location field of an event into a map link (Still can't understand why the built-in Calendar.app doesn't do this...)

Comment: Do you know if, in the Day View, you can add an event with a single touch in a given hour? And what about delay an event (without need to go to edit it and set a new time)?